# Rails 3 - Params question

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, parameters

I belive my question is rather simple but somehow I'm not reaching any success.

Let's say I have a model `test` and a `form_for (@test)`, to create a new one.

In my controller create method, I have `@test = Test.new(params[:test])`. But what if I want to get in this params just the name of the test or something like that?

Ex:

```
 @test_name = params[???]

 @test = Test.new(params[:test])
```

And in my view:

```
<%= form_for(@test) do |t| %>
...
  <div class="field">
    <%= t.label :name %><br />
    <%= t.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= t.label :field %><br />
    <%= t.text_area :field %>
  </div>
...
<% end %>
```

How can I do this?

Thanks for the future help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access it directly like:

```
@test_name = params[:test][:name]
```

You can also do:

```
@test = Test.new(params[:test])
@test_name = @test.name
```

I am curious as to why you are assigning the name to an instance variable though.

Comment: Thanks! Couldn't remember that. I'm doing tests with new databases and I want to create a database with the name the user will pass. On this database I will add the whole new test for example.

Answer (score 0):

You can just do:

```
@test = Test.new
@test.name = params[:test][:name]
@test.foo = params[:test][:foo]
# and so on...
```